# Correct Syntax for this SQL CASE?

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I am new to SQL plus . Could anyone help me figure out the syntax error for my code?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW BR_STATUS AS
SELECT CARTS_PER_CUSTOMER.loginName,CARTS_PER_CUSTOMER.number_of_carts,
       CASE WHEN (number_of_carts < 1 ) THEN 'BR-1 Satisfied.'
           ELSE 'BR-2 violated.'
       END AS 'BR-status'
FROM CARTS_PER_CUSTOMER;
```

Whenever I try to run this part of the code, I get this error message

> ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected.

I followed several oracle documentation for CASE, but can't figure out what I am writing wrong. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: remove the comma before the from. `END AS 'BR-status',`should be  `END AS "BR-status"`

Comment: Use double quotes for that column alias,  `"BR-status"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a unnecessary comma before `FROM` clause nothing wrong with `CASE` statement. Also use double quotes for `Alias` name instead of single quotes (thanks to Jarlh)

```
SELECT CARTS_PER_CUSTOMER.loginName,
       CARTS_PER_CUSTOMER.number_of_carts,
       CASE
         WHEN ( number_of_carts < 1 ) THEN 'BR-1 Satisfied.'
         ELSE 'BR-2 violated.'
       END AS "BR-status" --Remove the comma here
FROM   CARTS_PER_CUSTOMER;
```

Comment: Tried it without the comma `CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW BR_STATUS AS
SELECT CARTS_PER_CUSTOMER.loginName,CARTS_PER_CUSTOMER.number_of_carts,
CASE WHEN (number_of_carts < 1) THEN 'BR-1 Satisfied.'
ELSE 'BR-2 violated.'
END AS 'BR-status'
FROM CARTS_PER_CUSTOMER;` Still get the same error message.

Comment: Use double quotes for that column alias, `"BR-status"` .

Comment: @shamveel_ahammed - check now

Comment: @jarlh .. Thanks, it worked.. Should have used double quotes.

Comment: @prdp @jarlh Could you help me with this SQL query... I am still getting the same error message, but I think I am using the correct syntax  for CASE `SELECT inventoryItem.itemNum
CASE WHEN ( Count_same_color < 2  AND Count_same_size <2) THEN 'BR-1 Satisfied.'
ELSE 'BR-1 violated.'
END AS "BR-status"
FROM (
SELECT inventoryItem.itemNum,inventoryItem.itemSize,inventoryItem.itemColor,COUNT(inventoryItem.itemColor) AS Count_same_color,COUNT(inventoryItem.itemSize) AS Count_same_size
FROM  inventoryItem
GROUP BY inventoryItem.ItemColor,inventoryItem.ItemSize,inventoryItem.ItemNum
);`

Comment: @shamveel_ahammed - There is a missing comma after `itemNum` in your `select` list `inventoryItem.itemNum,CASE`